# Deprecated options when restarting openssh in Stretch

Tags: debian, openssh

Today, after doing updates in Debian Stretch, it started displaying these warnings when restarting the `ssh` service with my current config:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 17: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 18: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 29: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 36: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
[....] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 17: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 18: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 29: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 36: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
```

What is happening here?

Using Debian 9 with OpenSSH 7.4

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the current Stretch update, `openssh` version changed from 7.3 to 7.4, released on 2016-Dec-19.

As it can be inferred from the Release notes, and from @Jakuje comments, OpenSSH maintainers have removed the corresponding configuration options for good, as they are obsolete.

So the lines can be safely removed.

Also, take head of:

> Future deprecation notice
>
> We plan on retiring more legacy cryptography in future releases,
>   specifically:
>
> - In approximately August 2017, removing remaining support for the
>     SSH v.1 protocol (client-only and currently compile-time disabled).
> - In the same release, removing support for Blowfish and RC4 ciphers 
>     and the RIPE-MD160 HMAC. (These are currently run-time disabled).
> - Refusing all RSA keys smaller than 1024 bits (the current minimum
>     is 768 bits)
> - The next release of OpenSSH will remove support for running sshd(8)
>     with privilege separation disabled.
> - The next release of portable OpenSSH will remove support for
>     OpenSSL version prior to 1.0.1.

Comment: nope. This functionality is gone for few versions. Now they only removed the configuration options (because they didn't have any effect on SSH2). The problem is that you have configuration file not shipped by your distribution for some time (containing these options).

Comment: @Jakuje Interesting, I really did not pay attention to the client-only remark in the release notes until now.

Answer (score 33):

You can remove deprecated configuration lines with this:

```
sed -i '/KeyRegenerationInterval/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/ServerKeyBits/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/RSAAuthentication/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/RhostsRSAAuthentication/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/UsePrivilegeSeparation/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And restart SSH daemon: `systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: Hi,  congratulations on your first post. while your answer is technically correct, the question is more concerned with the `whys` than how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Nevertheless is this is a useful answer.

Comment: ..and confirms it is safe to do so without requiring any *newly* introduced preferred options ?